# Using Visual Studio C++ remote debugging for Linux on a non-MSBuild, non-CMake project

Tags: linux, remote, debug, c++, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio has features to support cross-platform projects, allowing a developer to build, run and debug a Linux program from within Visual Studio, by connecting to and executing on either the Windows Subsystem for Linux or a remote Linux machine.

Articles and documentation on VS's Linux debugging features cover how to debug programs that build via MSBuild or CMake. We have a number of C++ projects that build using an alternative build system. Is it possible to use VS's Linux debugging support to debug non-MSBuild/non-CMake projects?

If there's support for something as simple as telling VS to connect to a particular remote machine and launch the executable at a particular path that would be very useful. Even if we have to manually build on the Linux system and manually identify what source files the VS debugger should show, all we need is to be able to set breakpoints and step through code in VS while the program being debugged is running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

VS has a Makefile-Linux project. This allows various custom commands and paths to be configured in the project properties, enabling running and debugging a project on Linux with arbitrary build tools.